# Facebook login doesn't work inside Twitter iOS App

Tags: twitter, facebook-oauth

I have a RoR / JQuery Mobile app that uses Facebook OAuth for authentication. It all works fine when accessing it via any normal browser on desktop and mobile with one exception.

If a user clicks a link to the app within the Twitter iOS app the home page loads within an internal webview. If the user then clicks 'Sign In with Facebook' the authentication seems to be successful but when Facebook redirects the user back to the app the page never loads. It just displays a blank page and the network indicator at the top of the screen just keeps spinning. If I close the web view and click the link again the page loads fine because the user has already authenticated.

Has any one else had problems with Facebook Auth inside the twitter app on iOS? Any suggestions on how I can resolve this problem? Is it possible this is just a bug with the Twitter app on iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the solution. The facebook authentication process used a lot of redirects which I thought could be causing the problem (5 in total). After reviewing the process I realised I could remove one of the redirects and take the user directly to the page I wanted once they were authenticated.

- www.example.com (link from the tweet)
- www.example.com/auth/facebook (use clicks 'Login with Facebook')
- 1 - Redirect to: graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize
- 2 - Redirect to: www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
- 3 - Redirect to: www.example.com/auth/callback
- 4 - Redirect to: www.example.com/entry_path (***This has now been removed***)
- 5 - Redirect to: www.example.com/final_logged_in_path

The login process now works from within the Twitter iOS App.